# How do I return the users username in form of a link in a telegram bot so that I can just click on it and directly chat with them

Tags: ruby

The following piece of code is supposed to send a notification from my bot to me when a user is interacting with it. The message should contain the user name or better a link to directly chat with the user. How do I return the username inform of a clickable link to directly chat with the user. Or better how can I get a link to chatting with the user, whether he or she has a username or not.
I am using ruby programming language.

```
when '/yes'
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: 1233454991, text: " You have a new inquiry from #{message.from.username} ")
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. Just adding an @ in front of the literal string gives me the desired output

```
when '/yes'
        bot.api.send_message(chat_id: 1233454991, text: " You have a new inquiry from @#{message.from.username} ")
    end
```